# Flutter ImagePicker + saving this file on phone or firebase Storage and show it permanently

Tags: flutter, image, store, picker

I'm stuck. I am using  image_picker package and it is working perfectly - here is the code:

```
     File? image;
      Future pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
        try {
          final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
          if (image == null) return;
          final imageTemp = File(image.path);
          setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          print('Failed to pick image: $e');
        }
}
```

With that, I can pick an image and show it temporarily in the app but I would like to store this image on my device or Firebase Storage. Could someone help me with this step by step? ^^

Thanks a lot for all!!! Have a great day/night

Answer (score 0):

The image is stored in a temporary folder and can be found in **image.path**.
To move the image to specific location in the device you need first to handle the storage permission (you can use *permission_handler*).

You can the copy the file to the specific location you want.

For example:

```
File? image;
  Future pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemp = File(image.path);
      setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
      await imageTemp.copy('/your/specific/location');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }
```

The same thing can be done using firebase storage, please refer to this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage/example).